# How to add modules on serverless javascript nodejs function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, digital-ocean, serverless

I have a javascript serverless function, I need to connect to PostgreSQL database, I'm trying to use PG module to connect but I don't know how to import the package when I deploy the function on DigitalOcean.

[image]
[image: Got this error]